# How to insert a Div after <Div class="abc def"style='display"> or before <Div class="aB cd efG"> in Gmail Page using javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, gmail

i want to insert a button in ***Gmail*** page.i tried to insert using div id.it works.

but i want to insert,using the div class name.the class name like `<Div class="abc dsf "style='display">` and `<Div class="aB cd efG">`

How can i achieve this?

note:i also tried getElementsByClassName() and querySelecterall(),its not worked.
Sometimes it works,after refresh the page,it will disappear.

Comment: did you try `$('<button>B</button>').insertAfter('.abc.dec')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this-

```
$('<Div class="aB cd efG">').insertAfter('.abcdef');
```

http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

```
$('Your button HTML').insertBefore('.inner');
```

http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

Comment: @SanjuMonu: see the example   http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_insertafter

Comment: @ Suresh:i already seen it.it did not works for gmail page.i dont know,what is the problem actually?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ID of the parent element you can do this:

```
$('#<PARENT ID> div:eq(n)').before('Your button HTML');
```

n matches the n th element in descending order.

It's not exactly the solution you were looking for, but from what you explained this should suffice seeing that Gmail has fairly a static layout.

Comment: id is not static.it changed dynamically.

Comment: What button are you talking about? Ill take a look on my Gmail.

Comment: @ cinder:what u mean?

Comment: I meant, what div are you talking about or where do you want to place this button? I'll take a look at the Gmail page and see if I can help you at all.